# Where is the potion shop near the second dungeon?

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda

I'm looking for the potion shop near this dungeon. Where is it, and how do I get there?

Answer (score 4):

The potion shop near this dungeon is on the other side of the rock wall, so from the dungeon, head down one screen, right one screen, down one screen, left two, and up once, taking the far right path. Use the blue candle to burn the third bush from the top to reveal a staircase to the potion shop.

Comment: That guy really didn't want anyone to find his shop.